# is it possible to specify table cell using both % AND px?

Tags: html, css

Given a

```
<table width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td>Percentual<td>
        <td>Percentual<td>
        <td>Fixed 50px <td>
        <td>Fixed size<td>
        <td>Fixed size<td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Is it possible to have a table with some cells(`<td>`) fixed width(like `50px, 20px` ...) and other cells to divide in % (`25%, 25%, 50%`) the remaning free space?

I can't seem to be able to obtain this, since the % one take all the available space...

I only care of making it work in the laster firefox browser, but latest chrome and ie would be nice too

this didn't help [Can you mix % and px to align a table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2073221/can-you-mix-and-px-to-align-a-table)

Comment: Why did [Can you mix % and px to align a table?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2073221/can-you-mix-and-px-to-align-a-table) not help? Would a JavaScript solution work for you?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a CSS3 flexbox. It works like this:

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="flex">Percentual</div>
    <div class="flex">Percentual</div>
    <div class="fixed">Fixed 50px </div>
    <div class="fixed">Fixed size</div>
    <div class="fixed">Fixed size</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.box {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
}

.flex {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -moz-box-flex: 1;
}

div.fixed {
  width: 50px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DFTR4/ (resize your browser window)

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED**

You cant do this with CSS alone, you'll need to add some jquery such like this:

```
_width = ($('table').width() - $('#brian').width());

// Set widths as 'px'
//td_width_px = (_width / 3)
//$("td:not(#brian)").css("width",td_width_px+'px');

// Set widths as '%'    
td_width_pCent = (((_width / 3) / $('table').width()) * 100);
$("td:not(#brian)").css("width",td_width_pCent+'%');
```

Ive coded this up for you to see - http://jsfiddle.net/ajthomascouk/sVadG/1

*NB: there may be a better way to calculate the percentage, but i wanted to get you an answer.*

Comment: i see thank you, i am already using javascript (www.DataTables.net) but i don't know how to hook up into that, i'll try to look into it, thanks